# Does Capistrano 3 still put Rails logs in shared/log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have upgraded to Capistrano 3 and successfully deployed several Rails apps on a new server.

Previously with Capistrano 2 deployments the Rails logs magically went to /myapp/shared/log/production.log

With my Cap3 deployments the logs are in the app folder myapp/current/log/production.log

Is this intentional or have I missed setting something up?
Is there some special way to set it up so that they go to /shared/log ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just found the answer.

You need to uncomment the following line in deploy.rb

```
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
```